# How to find the RELATIVE PATH of a BLOB?

Tags: azure, devops, devops-services

I want to integrate my Blob Storage with Azure Data Bricks, I found this in azure documentation as a part of connection, Can someone help me where can I find blob_relative_path ?

```
blob_account_name = "azureopendatastorage"
blob_container_name = "citydatacontainer"
blob_relative_path = "Safety/Release/city=Boston"
blob_sas_token = r"?st=2019-02-26T02%3A34%3A32Z&se=2119-02-27T02%3A34%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2018-03- 
28&sr=c&sig=XlJVWA7fMXCSxCKqJm8psMOh0W4h7cSYO28coRqF2fs%3D"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative path of a blob is the path to the file of interest in your blob container. For instance, consider the following hierarchy:

```
Home > [blob_account_name] > [blob_container_name] > fakeDirectory/fakeSubDirectory/file.csv
```

The path to your file of interest in the identified container (i.e. *fakeDirectory/fakeSubDirectory/file.csv*) is the **blob_relative_path**.

Hope this helps!